# How to wait till signed in to Google Play Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using `BaseGameUtils` to access GPGS. Everything is working fine.

I would like to add a signin/signout button so the user has option to signin or signout from GPGS. The two methods I'm using are:

```
gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
gameHelper.signOut();
```

However, I would like to know exactly when the signin/signout occurred because I need to enable/disble Buttons accordingly.

I need to use `gameHelper.getSignedIn()`, however how can place it in a Loop (maybe separate thread) and proceed when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init):

> Finally, add sign-in and sign-out buttons to your layout. Implement
>   the following callbacks to notify your app when these buttons are
>   clicked:
>
> ```
> // Call when the sign-in button is clicked
> private void signInClicked() {
>     mSignInClicked = true;
>     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
> }
>
> // Call when the sign-out button is clicked
> private void signOutclicked() {
>     mSignInClicked = false;
>     Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
> }
> ```

so basically it recommends to disable them as soon as they are clicked. there are other places where `mSignInClicked` variable is changing its state as per need.